# How can I have an array in input form?

Tags: angular

I have a form with some input in a loop with lang and when I submit the form, the name of the input is a string rather than an object. Is it possible to return an object or what's the best way to create this object to send to an api?

My template

```
<form class="kt-form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" #f="ngForm">     
   <label>Name</label>
   <input *ngFor="let lang of aLang" 
      type="text" 
      class="form-control"
      name="translations.{{lang}}.name" 
      ngModel
   >
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

In my component

```
onSubmit (form: NgForm){
   let datas = form.value; 
   console.log(datas);
}
```

Now, I have this result:

```
Object { "translations.fr.name": "", "translations.nl.name": "", "translations.en.name": "" }
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: You want the name to be equal to  value of `translations.{{lang}}.name` or this as a string?

Comment: Can you explain your use case? You can send objects via POST-Method to an API. That is no problem. Afterall no matter what object will come from your #form you are free to create your own objects. Inputs always get a name as string and will be paired with the value you entered in an Object as you seen in your result.

Comment: @JosefKatič I would like have an object and not a string so
["translations": {"fr" : { "name":"value fr"}}}, {"translations": {"nl" : { "name":"value nl"}}}, {"translations": {"en" : { "name":"value en"}}}}

Comment: @liqSTAR yes I can create my object in the submit function before sent it to api but it would like to know if it's possible to have automatically an object since the form

Comment: Ah now i get it after you showed us your prefered form. Thats not possible without after editing.

Answer (score 3):

If I correctly understood the question, you should only send the language to the API. Therefore, change the HTML to:

```
 <form class="kt-form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" #f="ngForm">     
   <label>Name</label>
   <input *ngFor="let lang of aLang" 
      type="text" 
      class="form-control"
      name="{{lang}}" 
      ngModel
   >
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but I need an object with this structure of my input name because I have some other input with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it right then you want something like this.

```
   <input *ngFor="let lang of aLang" 
      type="text" 
      class="form-control"
      [attr.name]="lang.name" 
      ngModel>
```

`[]` these bracket's will make the attribute bindable so you can assing value from array or object. The `attr.` symbols that it's no an Angular `@Input()` property but a normal HTML attribute.

Comment: Hi, thanks but I must be use name attribute or I have an Angular error:

ERROR Error: "If ngModel is used within a form tag, either the name attribute must be set or the form
      control must be defined as 'standalone' in ngModelOptions.